# Why property value not changed at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms

This code is part of Strip Class

```
public class Strip : Control
{
    Color  backColor = Color.SeaGreen;
    Color  foreColor = Color.White;

    public TabStrip()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ContainerControl | ControlStyles.Selectable, true );
        Width = 350;
        Height = 250;
    }

    public override Color BackColor 
    {
        get { return backColor ; } 
        set { backColor = value; Invalidate();} 
    }

    public override Color ForeColor 
    { 
        get { return foreColor ; } 
        set { foreColor = value; } 
    }

}
```

When I change the property in the design time, the property works, but when I run the program, the property does not work and the chosen color does not appear.

Comment: _"When I change the property"_ - there are two. Which one is it?

Comment: Overridden properties and methods should usually forward the call to the base-method or property. But why are you overriding the colors in the first place? Why not just do `BackColor = Color.SeaGreen` in the constructor and skip the overrides?

Comment: [You probably want to review the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#notes-to-inheritors)

Comment: @Fildor ForeColor And BackColor

Comment: @JonasH  to call some methods

Comment: Appear where? You don't use the backing field in the shown code.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the overrides as

```
public override Color BackColor 
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; } 
        set {  base.BackColor = value; Invalidate();} 
    }
```

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#notes-to-inheritors):

> When overriding the ForeColor property in a derived class, use the base class's ForeColor property to **extend the base implementation**. Otherwise, you must provide all the implementation. You are not required to override both the get and set accessors of the ForeColor property; you can override only one if needed.

I.e. your current code will have different values for `this.BackColor`  and `base.BackColor`, and the painting code will use the later. If you insist on having separate color fields you also need to override the painting code to use these values.

Comment: Property value is "Control Color" not changed to chosen color

Comment: @Davied What property value? You mean in the designer? I can't say I fully understand what the designer does, as far as I'm concerned it is magic. But a workaround might be create something like a `SetBackColor(...)`-method. That way you can do whatever you want when this is called while avoiding potential problems in the designer.